# Stringify C preprocess

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

This is my first post, so if I'm being too vague or giving information that everyone would intuitively assume, please let me know.

I'm very new to writing in **C** and am just trying to get a better understanding of preprocessing.  I'm writing a simple program that can take in arguments either directly from the console using `gcc -Wall -std=c99 -DSEED=argument`, where my argument should be a an integer, or if the `-D` is not defined the user will input it.

The SEED value is simply used in `srand()`.  I'm very confused why my code will not compile if I put in an `-DSEED=a` as my argument while if I put `-DSEED=1` it will compile.  I'm getting a "âaâ undeclared (first use in this function)" error and really don't understand the difference between the two.  I thought the `#define` matched up the variable type with the input, so if I put in an "a" #SEED would be a char and if I put in a "1" #SEED would be an int.

If the SEED is not defined I'm using a `#ifndef SEED` command and this works well.
I think I'm supposed to "stringify" the input `SEED` and then can check if it is an integer or not.  After reading some articles online I'm trying to use:

```
#ifndef SEED
    //code
#else
    #define TO_STRING( input ) #input
    char c;
    c = TO_STRING( SEED )
    //Then I was going to use c to figure out if it was an int.
#endif
```

This is not working and anyone able to point out any misconceptions that you think that I may have would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT - So I did figure out why I was receiving the error message when trying the `-DSEED=a`, because it was reading it as a variable.

Comment: For one, a character can't be assigned a string literal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To stringify a `#define` you need to use a two-step approach:

```
#define _STRINGIFY(s) #s
#define STRINGIFY(s) _STRINGIFY(s)

...

#define SEED 123

...

const char * pszSeed = STRINGIFY(SEED); /* 'pszSeed' would point to "123" form here on. */
```

If you only want to use one character simply access it via `*pszSeed` or `pszSeed[0]`.

Comment: That definitely worked!  Thanks a lot.  Could you just tell me if I'm correct in my thinking why it actually works?  So the first _STRINGIFY(s) will make anything into a string because of the "#", the second STRINGIFY will place an expanded macro into the first #define?  Final followup.  Can I only use # in a macro to create a string?  Thanks so much for your help!